# How do I access variables outside of html document with a firefox extention?

Tags: javascript, html

Under window, in my case, there is, along with document, Game. I want to get data from game with a script that i inject into the main HTML. I have no problems doing this directly in the f12 console. However, there seems to be a reason I cannot get this information when using an extension. I'm extremely green, there's probably something super obvious I'm missing.

cceff.js

```
bruh1=document.createElement("button");
bruh1.addEventListener("click",function() {
var efflist = []; // all stuff that needs to be done in game
for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
  efflist[i]=Game.ObjectsById[i].storedCps/Game.ObjectsById[i].price
}
var max = efflist[0];
for(var i = 0; i < efflist.length; i++) {
  if(efflist[i]>max) {
    max=efflist[i];
  }
}
for(var i = 0; i < 16; i++){
  efflist[i]=efflist[i]/max;
  document.getElementById("productName"+i).innerHTML=Math.round((efflist[i]*100))/100;
} // return these values to background
});
bruh1.innerHTML="efficiency";
document.getElementById("topBar").appendChild(bruh1);
```

manifest

```
{
  "name": "cookie clicker efficiency thing",
  "version": "0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "pls",
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "pls",
    "default_icon": "icons/89.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

background.js

```
browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    browser.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file: 'cceff.js'
    });
});
```

Comment: `f12 console` is called "Developer tools"

Comment: I'm aware of this. I want to know what the difference is between Developer tools code and firefox extension code. The code in the main js runs properly in the dev tools console, but not in an extension. Do you know why?

Comment: Do you know what exactly fails? Syntax error, fails to load file, fails to find element, etc.?

Comment: Whenever I try to retrieve a variable from Game, it fails. I can get anything from document, and I can view document's parent (the window), which shows me game. But I can't access game for some reason.

Comment: I don't see where you define `Game`. Log it's values, maybe it's in different scope?

Comment: Game is defined in the website im making an extension for. What do you mean by different scope?

Comment: I've actually just found something interesting. I've been using the parent object to bring up the window (in dev tools). I do not see document in the child list. However, window.document works. Game is in the window children list. Does this mean anything?